# Define and use metadata on markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to write some documents in Markdown format that has a number of repeating characters that can be categorized, such as `author`, or `version`, or any other so called metadata.

How do I define the metadata and how do I refer to the metadata from the document?

Comment: What do you mean by "refer to the metadata from the document"?

Comment: What I'm referring as "metadata" here is like a variable within document. So let's say I've defined a variable called "version", I want to be able to refer to that "version" multiple times in various places within the document. If I want to change that "version", I just change it in one place.

Comment: Ah. GFM doesn't do that (nor do any other Markdown processors that I know). It's a markup format, not a templating language.